# IBAction not being called, but UI is updating?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ibaction, external-accessory

So the problem is I did not code this and am merely attempting to edit some code. It is code pertaining to a certain electrical I/O Board, which is an input/output control board for factory systems that is run by various iOS devices.

I cannot quite seem to figure out what the previous coder did within this class:

```
    //

//  AnalogVC.m 
//



#import "AnalogVC.h"

#import "AppDelegate.h"



@interface InputItem : NSObject

@property (weak,nonatomic) UISwitch *onSwitch;

@property (weak,nonatomic) UIProgressView *progressView;

@property (weak,nonatomic) UILabel *valueLabel;

@end



@implementation InputItem

AppDelegate *appDelegate;

+ (id)itemWithSwitch:(id)temp progress:(id)progress label:(id)label

{


    InputItem *item = [[InputItem alloc] init];

    item.onSwitch = temp;

    item.progressView = progress;

    item.valueLabel = label;

    return item;

}



- (void)setDisconnected

{


    self.onSwitch.on = NO;

    self.onSwitch.enabled = NO;

    self.valueLabel.text = @"0.000 v";

    self.progressView.progress = 0;



}



- (void)setOn

{



self.onSwitch.on = YES;

    self.onSwitch.enabled = YES;

    self.valueLabel.text = @"0.000 v";

    self.progressView.progress = 0;

[appDelegate watchPins:@"testing ON"];

}



- (void)setOff

{


    self.onSwitch.on = NO;

    self.onSwitch.enabled = YES;

    self.valueLabel.text = @"0.000 v";

    self.progressView.progress = 0;

[appDelegate watchPins:@"testing OFF"];

}



- (void)setValue:(double)value

{

    if (self.onSwitch.on)

    {

        self.valueLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.3f v",value];

        self.progressView.progress = value/5.0;

if(value > 0.8){

[appDelegate watchPins:@"testing VALUE"];

}

    }

}

@end



@interface AnalogVC ()

{


    NSArray *_inputItems;

    AppDelegate *appDelegate;

    NSMutableArray *channel0Values;



    UIColor *custom1;

    UIColor *custom2;

    UIColor *custom3;

    UIColor *custom4;

}



@property (nonatomic) NCBoardManager *manager;



@property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *inputSwitch0;

@property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *inputSwitch1;

@property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *inputSwitch2;

@property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *inputSwitch3;

@property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *inputSwitch4;

@property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *inputSwitch5;



@property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UIProgressView *inputProgress0;

@property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UIProgressView *inputProgress1;

@property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UIProgressView *inputProgress2;

@property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UIProgressView *inputProgress3;

@property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UIProgressView *inputProgress4;

@property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UIProgressView *inputProgress5;



@property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *inputValue0;

@property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *inputValue1;

@property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *inputValue2;

@property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *inputValue3;

@property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *inputValue4;

@property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *inputValue5;



@property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UISlider *outputSlider0;

@property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UISlider *outputSlider1;



@property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UIStepper *outputStepper0;

@property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UIStepper *outputStepper1;



@property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *outputValue0;

@property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *outputValue1;





- (IBAction)inputChannelChanged:(UISwitch *)sender;

- (IBAction)outputSliderMoved:(UISlider *)sender;

- (IBAction)outputSliderStopped:(UISlider *)sender;

- (IBAction)outputStepperChanged:(UIStepper *)sender;

@end



@implementation AnalogVC{}





//////////////////////////////

#pragma mark View Lifecycle

//////////////////////////////





- (void)viewDidLoad

{

    [super viewDidLoad];

        NSLog(@"Analog VC loaded");

    _inputItems = @[[InputItem itemWithSwitch:_inputSwitch0 progress:_inputProgress0 label:_inputValue0],

                    [InputItem itemWithSwitch:_inputSwitch1 progress:_inputProgress1 label:_inputValue1],

                    [InputItem itemWithSwitch:_inputSwitch2 progress:_inputProgress2 label:_inputValue2],

                    [InputItem itemWithSwitch:_inputSwitch3 progress:_inputProgress3 label:_inputValue3],

                    [InputItem itemWithSwitch:_inputSwitch4 progress:_inputProgress4 label:_inputValue4],

                    [InputItem itemWithSwitch:_inputSwitch5 progress:_inputProgress5 label:_inputValue5]];



    _manager = [NCBoardManager sharedBoardManager];



    __unsafe_unretained AnalogVC *vc = self;

    [_manager setAnalogInputHandling:dispatch_get_main_queue()

                              filter:^(NCAnalogInputs *inputs){ return YES; }

                             handler:^(NCAnalogInputs *inputs){ [vc setAnalogInputs:inputs]; }];





    //  Register for notifications

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self

                                             selector:@selector(boardConnected:)

                                                 name:CONNECTED_NOTIFICATION

                                               object:nil];



    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self

                                             selector:@selector(boardDisconnected:)

                                                 name:DISCONNECTED_NOTIFICATION

                                               object:nil];

}



- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated

{

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [self updateAnalogInputs];

    [self updateAnalogOutputs];



    custom1 = [UIColor whiteColor];

    custom2 = [UIColor darkGrayColor];

    custom3 = [UIColor blackColor];

    custom4 = [UIColor colorWithRed:.97 green:.97 blue:.588 alpha:1.0];



    CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];

    gradient.frame = self.view.bounds;

    gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[custom2 CGColor], (id)[custom1 CGColor], (id)[custom2 CGColor], nil];

    gradient.startPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0);

    gradient.endPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 1.0);

    gradient.locations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0], [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.5], [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0], nil];

    [self.view.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];



    [self.inputSwitch0 setOnTintColor:custom4];

    [self.inputSwitch1 setOnTintColor:custom4];

    [self.inputSwitch2 setOnTintColor:custom4];

    [self.inputSwitch3 setOnTintColor:custom4];

    [self.inputSwitch4 setOnTintColor:custom4];

    [self.inputSwitch5 setOnTintColor:custom4];



    [self.inputSwitch0 setTintColor:custom3];

    [self.inputSwitch1 setTintColor:custom3];

    [self.inputSwitch2 setTintColor:custom3];

    [self.inputSwitch3 setTintColor:custom3];

    [self.inputSwitch4 setTintColor:custom3];

    [self.inputSwitch5 setTintColor:custom3];



    self.inputProgress0.trackTintColor = custom3;

    self.inputProgress1.trackTintColor = custom3;

    self.inputProgress2.trackTintColor = custom3;

    self.inputProgress3.trackTintColor = custom3;

    self.inputProgress4.trackTintColor = custom3;

    self.inputProgress5.trackTintColor = custom3;



    self.inputProgress0.progressTintColor = custom4;

    self.inputProgress1.progressTintColor = custom4;

    self.inputProgress2.progressTintColor = custom4;

    self.inputProgress3.progressTintColor = custom4;

    self.inputProgress4.progressTintColor = custom4;

    self.inputProgress5.progressTintColor = custom4;



    self.outputSlider0.minimumTrackTintColor = custom4;

    self.outputSlider1.minimumTrackTintColor = custom4;

    self.outputSlider0.maximumTrackTintColor = custom3;

    self.outputSlider1.maximumTrackTintColor = custom3;



    self.outputSlider0.thumbTintColor = custom3;

    self.outputSlider1.thumbTintColor = custom3;



    if(_manager.isBoardConnected)

    {

        self.outputStepper0.tintColor = custom4;

        self.outputStepper1.tintColor = custom4;

        self.outputStepper0.enabled = TRUE;

        self.outputStepper1.enabled = TRUE;

        self.outputSlider0.enabled = TRUE;

        self.outputSlider1.enabled = TRUE;

    }

    else

    {

        self.outputStepper0.tintColor = custom2;

        self.outputStepper1.tintColor = custom2;

        self.outputStepper0.enabled = FALSE;

        self.outputStepper1.enabled = FALSE;

        self.outputSlider0.enabled = FALSE;

        self.outputSlider1.enabled = FALSE;

    }

}





//////////////////////////////

#pragma mark Rotation Calls

//////////////////////////////





- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations

{

    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;

}



- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate

{

    return FALSE;

}





//////////////////////////

#pragma mark Board Calls

//////////////////////////





- (void)boardConnected:(NSNotification *)notification

{

    [self updateAnalogInputs];

    [self updateAnalogOutputs];



    self.outputStepper0.enabled = TRUE;

    self.outputStepper1.enabled = TRUE;

    self.outputSlider0.enabled = TRUE;

    self.outputSlider1.enabled = TRUE;



    self.outputStepper0.tintColor = custom4;

    self.outputStepper1.tintColor = custom4;

}



- (void)boardDisconnected:(NSNotification *)notification

{

    [self updateAnalogInputs];

    [self updateAnalogOutputs];



    self.outputStepper0.enabled = FALSE;

    self.outputStepper1.enabled = FALSE;

    self.outputSlider0.enabled = FALSE;

    self.outputSlider1.enabled = FALSE;



    self.outputStepper0.tintColor = custom2;

    self.outputStepper1.tintColor = custom2;

}



- (void)updateAnalogInputs

{


    uint8_t channel = self.manager.analogInputChannels;

    switch (self.manager.analogInputStatus)

    {

        case NCInputConnected:

            //  Check if channels we left on

            if (channel) self.manager.analogInputChannels = 0;

            [_inputItems makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(setOff)];

            break;

        case NCInputDisconnected:

            [_inputItems makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(setDisconnected)];

            break;

        case NCInputLiveUpdating:

            for (InputItem *item in _inputItems)

            {

                //if (channel & 1) [item setOn];

                //else             [item setOff];

                channel >>= 1;

            }

            break;

        case NCInputSampling:

            [_inputItems makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(setDisconnected)];

            break;

        case NCInputTransfering:

            [_inputItems makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(setDisconnected)];

            break;

    }



}





- (void)setAnalogInputs:(NCAnalogInputs *)inputs

{


    int i = 0;

    uint8_t channels = inputs.channels;

    for (InputItem *item in _inputItems)

    {

        if (channels & 1)

        {

            [item setValue:[inputs valueForChannel:i]];


        }

        channels >>= 1;

        i++;

    }

}



- (void)updateAnalogOutputs

{

    BOOL connected = [self.manager isBoardConnected];



    self.outputSlider0.value = self.manager.analogOutput0;

    self.outputSlider0.enabled = connected;

    self.outputStepper0.value = self.outputSlider0.value * 1000;

    self.outputStepper0.enabled = connected;

    self.outputValue0.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.3f v",self.outputSlider0.value];



    self.outputSlider1.value = self.manager.analogOutput1;

    self.outputSlider1.enabled = connected;

    self.outputStepper1.value = self.outputSlider1.value * 1000;

    self.outputStepper1.enabled = connected;

    self.outputValue1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.3f v",self.outputSlider1.value];

}





///////////////////////////////

#pragma mark IBAction Methods

///////////////////////////////



- (IBAction)inputChannelChanged:(UISwitch *)sender

{

NSLog(@"TEST");

InputItem *item = [_inputItems objectAtIndex:sender.tag];

    uint8_t channels = self.manager.analogInputChannels;

    if (sender.on)

    {

        channels  |= (1 << sender.tag);

        [item setOn];



    }

    else

    {

        channels &= ~(1 << sender.tag);

        [item setOff];

    }

    if (!self.manager.analogInputChannels) [self.manager startAnalogLiveUpdating];

    else if(!channels) [self.manager stopAnalogLiveUpdating];



    self.manager.analogInputChannels = channels;

}



- (IBAction)outputSliderMoved:(UISlider *)sender

{

    if (!sender.tag)

    {

        self.manager.analogOutput0 = sender.value;

        self.outputValue0.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.3f v",sender.value];

    }

    else

    {

        self.manager.analogOutput1 = sender.value;

        self.outputValue1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.3f v",sender.value];

    }

}



- (IBAction)outputSliderStopped:(UISlider *)sender

{

    if (!sender.tag)

    {

        self.manager.analogOutput0 = sender.value;

        self.outputStepper0.value = round(sender.value * 1000.0);

        self.outputValue0.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.3f v",self.outputStepper0.value/1000.0];

    }

    else

    {

        self.manager.analogOutput1 = sender.value;

        self.outputStepper1.value = round(sender.value * 1000.0);

        self.outputValue1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.3f v",self.outputStepper1.value/1000.0];

    }

}



- (IBAction)outputStepperChanged:(UIStepper *)sender

{

    float value = sender.value/1000.0;



    if (!sender.tag)

    {

        self.manager.analogOutput0 = value;

        self.outputSlider0.value = value;

        self.outputValue0.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.3f v",value];

    }

    else

    {

        self.manager.analogOutput1 = sender.value/1000.0;

        self.outputSlider1.value = value;

        self.outputValue1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.3f v",value];

    }

}



@end
```

The problem I am having is I cannot figure out how to take values to and from the UIProgressViews that are on the storyboard (which is, like you said, a trivial concept). However with this set up it is rather convoluted.

Second problem is that; I am not sure if there is a way I can debug this as the application **only runs when the external device (the nanospark controller board) is connected to the iPod.**

The last but final problem I am having is that I am assuming the IBAction InputChannelChanged is being called (cannot debug this regularly with a breakpoint as aforementioned because it requires the external device to run the application), but when I run the application it does everything it should and the buttons react correctly to what the original software developer had coded.

This means that if I add my texting method to the IBAction (by adding [appDelegate watchPins@"TEST"]) it does not send the text to the user, but the buttons do still do what they should have done in concordance to the previous developers' aspirations.... this implies that the IBAction method is indeed being called... but then why isn't my text going through? I know that [appDelegate watchPins:@"TEST"]; should work as I have used it within several of his other classes.

Here is a screenshot displaying the UI of the AnalogVC.m:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNpZk.png

**Do not feel obligated to answer all of these questions it's just I felt it necessary to provided all three for greater context of the problem. Thanks and sorry for the TL;DR.**

I'd upload the image but I do not have the required minimum reputation.

I have tried to add another IBAction just to see if the buttons react to that; still nothing even if I copied the exact code from the other working classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual rule is to check your outlets and actions in IB (Interface Builder). More often than not it's a broken link.

If that's not it, you're going to need to figure out a way to debug this. How did the original developer write the app if they did not have a way to simulate the dedicated hardware?

Its impossible for your readers on SO to know what is preventing the app from working correctly.

One option would be to add log statements to your IBAction methods, run a development build the program in the field, and then connect the iPad to Xcode and view the console log to look at the output of the log statements.

By the way, you posted hundreds of lines of code, much of it boilerplate code that was added by Xcode, and much of the remainder irrelevant to the problem you're trying to solve. It's a good idea to whittle down the code you post to the relevant sections so your readers can zero in on what's important. Otherwise they are likely to lose patience with scrolling through mounds of irrelevant code to try to find the bits that relate to your post.

Comment: I physically have the hardware with me. I will concise down the code as well, my apologies. I will try out the logs and make an edit whence  completed. My reasoning for adding so much is even trudging through the class myself I couldn't really understand it and had assumed the entirety of the class would be necessary for a clear understanding from someone else.

Comment: Well... if you, the one with the project in Xcode, can't tell which classes are relevant to the problem you're having, it's VERY unlikely that those reading code you've pasted will be able to tell the cause of the problem.

Comment: I never said I couldn't understand what was or wasn't relevant to the problem, there is no need for attitude; we're adults here. I realize it was a bit much code but I had my reasoning behind thinking it would be useful for someone with a bit more experience to see where things were being declared or how the implementation and methods communicated between each other. I take your advice obviously and will improve posts in the future sarcastic and snide tones aren't really necessary.